# Save query using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have form with multiple textboxes that are used to filter Subforms. The Subform Source Objects are queries. In order to filter the Subforms I update the query SQL and reassign the query as the source object on the subform.

```
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("MyQuery")
qdf.SQL = strNewSQL
mySubForm.SourceObject = "Query.MyQuery"
```

The filtering works correctly. However when I close my form, I get a message asking if I want to save changes to the queries. How can I avoid this message?

Edit:- Following comment by @June7, closing form using

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, "MyForm", acSaveNo
```

solved my issue.

It is also possible to close the form using an embedded macro and setting prompt = No.

Comment: I tested code and don't get prompt. How are you closing form? Edit question with full procedure

Comment: Thank you for this. I was using an embedded macro to close the form. I have now changed this to use `DoCmd.Close acForm, "MyForm", acSaveNo` and now I do not get the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Using VBA instead of embedded macro solved your issue but consider that code can be simplified to:

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyQuery").SQL = strNewSQL
Me.mySubForm.SourceObject = "Query.MyQuery"
```